# a random matchmaking system between a pool of players

Tags: python, beginner

Since last month I have been practicing python, and yesterday I tried to make a simple app that reads a random list of players and based on that it makes a random fight between 2 random players.
I dont know if there is something that I can change to make the program be better.

Something I tried to do, was to make the program not show me a match between 2 players that already had been matched before, but I couldn't figure out how to make that :/. I would appreciate any tip or recommendation =).

```
import random

players = []

print("Welcome to match generator\nType every player name. In case of no input, the program will stop reading any new players.")
while 1:
    player = input()
    if player == "":
        break
    else:
        players.append(player)


while 1:
    p1 = random.choice(players)
    p2 = random.choice(players)
    while p2 == p1: p2 = random.choice(players)
    print(" ".join([p1, "vs", p2]))

    repeat = input("\nGenerate a new fight?\n1. Yes\n2. No\n")
    if repeat == "2": break
```

Comment: Re. _make the program not show me a match between 2 players that already had been matched before_ - there are many approaches (performing differently, depending on your player list length) - but Code Review does not support filling in new features, only reviewing existing ones.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you have modified the code and want a review of the new code you can ask a follow up question with a link back to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Add functions and a `__main__` guard.

Don't prepend `\n` to the beginning of your last `input`; that's an unrelated linebreak that should be associated with previous output.

Consider making an iterator function for gathering player names.

Do not loop to choose unique random players; use `sample`.

`join` is overkill for your player printing.

### Suggested

```py
import random
from typing import Iterator


def get_players() -> Iterator[str]:
    print("Type every player name. In case of no input, the program will stop reading any new players.")
    while True:
        player = input()
        if player == "":
            break
        yield player


def main() -> None:
    print("Welcome to match generator")
    players = tuple(get_players())
    
    while True:
        p1, p2 = random.sample(players, k=2)
        print(p1, 'vs', p2)
        print()

        repeat = input("Generate a new fight?\n1. Yes\n2. No\n")
        if repeat == "2":
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Whenever feasible, use command-line arguments rather than interactivity**.
Your program could be a standard command-line script: take some player names
from the user and then print out random pairings. Experienced programmers would
generally implement that behavior via command-line arguments rather than
resorting to the kind of dialogue-based programs that one tends to see in
low-quality introductory programming materials. Programs in that vein are
simultaneously a hassle to write (prompting the user, getting replies via
`input()`, validating the input, etc) and a poor guide to what a person
needs to know to become proficient. Stop thinking about Python scripts as a
human-computer interaction. Instead, think about them as powerful tools that
(1) take inputs when started (command-line arguments and potentially
configuration files or environment variables), (2) do some useful stuff based
on those inputs, and (3) exit politely without annoying humans with pesky
`input()` requests. [Apologies for the rant, but I offer it as sincere advice if you are serious about programming.]

```
import sys
from random import shuffle

def main(players):
    shuffle(players)
    for i in range(1, len(players), 2):
        print(players[i - 1], 'vs', players[i])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**Command-line arguments can do a lot**. The example above just
takes the player names as ordinary command line arguments, but
this mechanism can support many usage scenarios. For example, if you want to control
the number of random pairings, you could use an option, as illustrated
below. To learn how to create programs like this, see [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

```text
# Print as many pairings as possible.
python matchups.py A B C D E F G H

# Print a specific number of pairings.
python matchups.py -n 2 A B C D E F G H
```

Comment: Ok, I actually didn't even thought of making it like that, but now i like it lol.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I notice first that might improve your code quality:

#### Don't use an unnecessary infinite loop

```py
while player := input():
  players.append(player)
```

This is much cleaner code then what you had before, where essentially `player` is assigned the value of the user input in the condition of the loop, which fails if the string is empty. While the string is not empty, append that player to the list.

#### Ensure valid input

This isn't exactly your code per se, but it's important to check that the user, e.g. has entered at least 2 players, or your code will break.

#### Use an actual technique to get different random values

I would say that your current code is inefficient and quite messy. Fortunately, this is actually very easy to implement in conjunction with your desire to not select players that have already been in a match. The trick is simple: remove a player once we pick them, so when we pick another player it's guaranteed not to be the same one, and additionally players that have already been in a match will no longer be chosen. The code looks something like this:

```py
# inside your loop

p1 = random.choice(players)
players.remove(p1)

p2 = random.choice(players)
players.remove(p2)
```

#### Fancy != elegant

Like the other post mentioned, your use of `join` is complete overkill. What's wrong with `print(p1, "vs", p2)`?

---

The modified code looks something like this:

```py
import random

players = []

print("Welcome to match generator")
print("Type every player name. In case of no input, the program will stop reading any new players.")

while player := input():
  players.append(player)

while True:
  p1 = random.choice(players)
  players.remove(p1)
  
  p2 = random.choice(players)
  players.remove(p2)
  
  print(p1, "vs", p2)
  
  print("Generate a new fight?")
  print("1. Yes")
  print("2. No")
  
  if input() == "2": break
```

Comment: `players.remove` is not a good choice, for two reasons: first, it breaks reuse of the player sequence on subsequent iterations; and second it's more complicated than just doing a `sample()`

Comment: This answer also has indentation that breaks PEP8.

Comment: _fancy != elegant_ - indeed, and I'd offer that `player := input()` is more fancy than useful. Having a truthy loop termination criterion based on a walrus departs fairly significantly from Python's "explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: Your `players.remove` was probably an attempt to answer OP's question about avoiding repeat pairs, but I think what they asked for and what you implemented are two very different things. OP wanted to avoid repeat _pairs_, not repeat _players_.

Comment: So overall I'm afraid that without some modification I cannot recommend this answer as a constructive review.

Answer (score 0):

> Something I tried to do, was to make the program not show me a match between 2 players that already had been matched before.

One way to do this is to shuffle the whole player list, then match `players[0]` with `players[1]`, `players[2]` with `players[3]`, and so on. In code:

```py
random.shuffle(players)
for i in range(0, len(players) - 1, 2):
    print(players[i], 'vs.', players[i + 1])
```

If there's another round of match ups, shuffle the list again and repeat.

Comment: This does not ensure avoiding repeat player matches, since - after the random shuffle - the same matches could very well reoccur.